# How to refer within a formula to a cell that contains a wildcard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a COUNTIF formula as below:

```
=countif (Table_Name[Field_Name],C1)
```

Where, C1 can be a valid number or an asterisk.

The problem is, when I put the character * in C1, the formula doesn't work, but when I insert a valid number it works.

Even if I write:

```
=countif (Table_Name[Field_Name],"*")
```

the formula returns zero, which is not correct.

Furthermore, the

```
=countif (Table_Name[Field_Name],*)
```

returns error.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `"*"` looks for text only, for numbers, instead of wildcard you can use e.g. `">0"`

Comment: It works. I would suggest you to write it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards (`"*"` `"?"`) only for lookup in texts.

For numbers, you can add simple criteria (e.g. `">0"`, `"<>-1"`).